# Why am I getting exception: abstructmethoderror while calling setXmlStandalone() method in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-parsing

I have a `Parser.java API` program which has a function `XMLParser` which calls `setXmlStandalone()` of import `javax.xml.parsers.Document` class

I have written a program say **"ABC.java"** which calls `Parser API`. It runs well in Eclipse. But when I call this program using an application I am working on, it gives exception **"abstractmethoderror"** on line.

```
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.newDocument();
try { doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
} catch (org.w3c.dom.DOMException de)
```

**Any idea why I am getting this exception while calling from application but not in Eclipse???**

Comment: may be the required jars are missing from classpath, or may be version incompatibility

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but If jar files were missing, It could have thrown exception at earlier stage. and How do I make sure of versions. I have compiled with 1.7 in Eclipse and Apllication which I am using to call has also same version of compiler

Comment: Can anyone help with this??

Comment: what all jars have you included for the project in Eclipse?

Comment: I have included ReverseXSL.jar as external reference library. which has Parser class.

Comment: add the same jar in classpath in the application

Comment: I have added jars in class path, still it doesn't work. I created a demo project with same kind of structure with reference to external jar, that worked fine I n application but my original project still throws error. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it was compaitibility issue I believe. I made changes to code and it worked.